# Will i lose any data if i transfer backups data folders and not the whole backups.backupdb?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, external-disk

I can transfer dates folders(backups from different dates),but i can't transfer backups.backupdb.
Will i lose something if i just transfer those files?

[image]

Is there a way to transfer somewhere backups.backupdb if it's on external HDD and not in my TimeMachine?
I saved backups a long time ago from my old MacBook Pro with Mojave.
I saved them on external Transcend HDD and now i can't transfer them anywhere :

1.To another HDD?No,i can't,i get endless copying of files.

2.To my Mac?NO!**''The volume is wrong format for backup''**

3.Encrypt backups inside the HDD and transfer dmg verison?NO!
**''Operation failed: Operation not permitted''**

4.Just wait till endless copying end?Well,it won't end.

Please help me or just say it's just impossible in MacOS to transfer your backups if they are on external HDD

Comment: You should get the wanted result by combining [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/458507/489896) answer and the `mv` command in Terminal (see https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/manage-files-apddfb31307-3e90-432f-8aa7-7cbc05db27f7/mac)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with [Big Sur, (incl Monterey, Ventura...) TimeMachine uses snapshot technology on APFS volumes](https://www.macworld.com/article/234913/macos-big-sur-supports-time-machine-on-apfs-formatted-drives-but-there-are-a-few-catches.html). Quoting Boromir, one does not simply copy or move an APFS volume. The `.backupdb` file is no longer used.  I'm placing this answer here, not necessarily for you(the OP) but for others searching for the same answer.