# Huge Backups.backupdb folder on the same local drive

Tags: time-machine, macos

I recently noticed that my newly installed local disk is running out of space on High Sierra. After some investigation, I found a `Backups.backupdb` folder that was taking up a significant amount of space on the disk. I was surprised to find multiple backups of the same disk in the folder, even though I had never selected this disk as a Time Machine backup drive.

When I ran the `tmutil listbackups` command in Terminal, it did not list the backups on the local disk, indicating that they are ownerless and essentially useless. However, I encountered an issue when attempting to delete the `Backups.backupdb` folder.

I am unsure why this situation occurred and would appreciate any insight or suggestions. Also I would like how to delete the `Backups.backupdb` folder and free up space on my local disk in the most sure and secure way.

Comment: Also, the `Backups.backupdb` folder is protected by the system it is therefore extremely hard to delete (as well as any of its contents) by normal deletion means.

Comment: This may help you:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/243874/119271

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why aren't you allowed to delete the `Backups.backupdb` folder?

The `Backups.backupdb` folder is protected by the system and is therefore extremely hard to delete (as well as any of its contents) through normal deletion means (e.g. Drag it to trash or select and press cmd+delete).

You could normally run `sudo rm -rf Backups.backupdb` to delete this folder but as mentioned above, it won't work and normally show that error message (at least for me) :

> Operation Not Permitted

### How to fix that error? (And delete the folder)

Based on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/162690/how-can-i-delete-time-machine-files-using-the-commandline) old answer, to delete the `Backups.backupdb` folder, run this command in Terminal :

```
sudo /System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass rm -rfv Backups.backupdb
```

This will bypass every restriction that are in place causing it to show the error shown above ("Operation Not Permitted") when running `sudo rm -rf Backups.backupdb`.

Note that "bypass" is still located in `/System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass` for me.