# How to safely delete old Time Machine backups from external disk

Tags: macos, time-machine

I can browse through Backups.backupdb on the disk, and find ancient folders I would like to delete to save space on that disk.

I am wary of simply deleting those in case the oldest ones have lots of data important to Time Machine (e.g. maybe the incremental backups are done from the bottom up)

How can I reclaim storage space on that disk by removing unnecessary old Time Machine backups?

Comment: I agree with @Gilby . Also, see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/458507/489896) on how to delete the `Backups.backupdb` folder.

Comment: I'd recommend the answer that describes right-clicking on the folder in the Time Machine app view. This will delete all backups of that folder. Messing with deleting individual backups is, in my view, a bit risky, and you could end up breaking the whole archive. TM generally works best when not interfered with.

Comment: Also, while Time Machine backups are incremental a in only backing up/copying changed data, each „timeslice“ on the backup disk represents a full backup.